# Cannot apply migration on SQL Server running on Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, ef-core-2.2

I'm working on Docker-based microservices project, EF Core 2.2 Web API and other technologies and I'm having a problem applying the EF Core migration on the target container and the error message below below is displayed:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Here my SQL Server container configuration:

```
  sqlserver:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    container_name: sqlserver
    volumes:
      - sqlserverdata:/var/opt/mssql 
    ports:
      - "1434:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y 
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
      - SA_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And I was trying to run the below EF Core command via Powershell

```
dotnet ef migrations remove --configuration 20190803101841_XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Is your connection string right? Should be something like `Data Source=(local)\MSSQLSERVER; User ID=sa; Password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: The connection string was fine and I my EF Command was wrong, I have changed as below: dotnet ef migrations remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the problem because I'm using a migration name instead of the configuration.

So I solved the problem simply by modifying my EF Core command as below:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```